# Choosing WiFi vs Cellular when both are available

Tags: android, xamarin, wifi, simultaneous, cellular-network

I am developing a xamarin android app. I need to perform 2 things

1. Connect to a local device via WiFi (no internet connection) and communicate with it via TCP.
2. Communicate with server via Mobile data to send/receive information.

So far it seems like the moment i connect to WiFi i no longer can connect to my webserver, is there a way to programatically choose what route to use? We could do this in Windows Mobile and even in iOS.